# Android (notifications) - C++ Code turns on bluetooth - but no notification is shown in Notification Bar

Tags: android, bluetooth, notifications, wifi

Hey Guys.
I'm working with a collegue on a android app. At some point the app starts Bluetooth by itself without user interaction. This is written in C++. Now I want to turn the main Bluetooth Symbol on, to inform the user that Bluetooth is turned on.The same for WiFi.

I could create my own notifications, but that's not what I want.

How can I access the main notification symbols in Java?

Another question about notifications:
I have a notification for my main app. Every time I click on the notification the app is restarted (onCreate is called). When I click the Home Button, when my app is in the front is shows the home screen and by clicking on the app symbol it resumes the app (onResume is called). I want exactly the same behaviour when I click on the notification. How do I achieve this?

thanks in advance

Comment: it should automatically show up i think... just takes a little bit to start up bluetooth

Comment: **Another question about notifications:** you might want to try setting the `android:launchMode` of your Activity to `singleTop` and override `onHandleNewIntent` in your activity.

Comment: Then I just have to call the onResume() in my activity and will continue from there where it was before. Will it loose the variables?

I'll try this out later this day.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, this works only if you call it from Java, or call into corresponding Java methods via JNI, which will update the proper notifications for you.

Comment: Is there no other way to update this so that Android realizes that it has to update all notifications and widgets etc. If not, then I have to create my own notification.
I have access to the native methods via jni, does anybody maybe know if there is a proper native "updatenotifications" or "informJavaAboutBluetoothTurnedOn" method?

Comment: I am not aware of native methods, even if they are exposed in a more recent SDK versions they might not be available in all Android handsets. Calling the Java methods seems like the only usable option.